# Q: Google Sheet returns value based on cell and ture false

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have created a Google Sheet as shown below.

[image]

What I need is to update the result automatically. For example, Paul passed the Lvl1 exam, C2 will automatically show 1. If Ben failed the exam, C4 will show 0. Also, if I sorted the sheet by date which will be added, can I still get the correct data?

```
=iferror(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(D2:D1000,SMALL(IF(E2:E1000=TRUE,ROW(C2:C1000)-ROW(C2)+1),1))), )
```

I used this and it shows the correct level on first passed result. What should I do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Why this needs to be an array formula? Simply check column E and D, and return the appropriate value. Using two nested if formulas should address your need.

Comment: What if i add more name? It is because i would like to make it a automatic sheet that i enter the a new row of data, it will check if the person passed the exam or not and show the level.

Comment: Make it a table. In a table when you add a row, it automatically generates the other columns.

Comment: Does it means that i have to sort the data and use the vlookup fuction?

Comment: No, use Index and Match together. No need to sort.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, i use Index and Match together and i only get a the first Paul instead of the Paul on row 5.
Am I missing something??

Comment: Do it on the ID instead of Name

Comment: I do it on the ID and it stills show the result of the first row which is empty.

Comment: Edit the question please and show your work.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to sort this, try `ARRAYFORMULA`.

Clear column C, then add this in cell C1:

`=arrayformula(if(row($E1:$E)=1,"Level",if($E1:$E="","",if($E1:$E=true,1,0))))`

It will cascade the formulas down, and even let you sort the range provided you have created a filter with row 1 as the header.